# Matlab: find a value in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, find

I have the following matrix:

```
A= [23 34 45 0 0 0; 21 34 0 0 23 11; 34 23 0 0 0 22]
```

I want to find if a value is present and if it's present, I want to find the following values.

Eg I want to find in A the value 23, if it's present I want like output a matrix only with 23 and its following values

```
B= [23 34 45 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 23 11; 0 23 0 0 0 22]
```

Comment: Please add what you've tried so far.

Comment: I believe you are looking for the `find` function - finding rows with 23 and re-indexing.

Comment: I have find the single value 23 using find but I have no idea how to put in a matrix the following values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting question, and I have a non-loopy answer, it uses the interesting effect of `cumsum` and `find` to great efficiency.

```
G = zeros(size(A));
T = find(A==23);
G(T) = 1;
mask = cumsum(G,2)>0;

result = mask .* A;

>> result =

23    34    45     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0    23    11
 0    23     0     0     0    22
```

This is I think, one of the more efficient way of doing this.

========EDIT========

even better, use logical indexing:

```
B = A.*(cumsum(A==23,2)>0);
```

Thanks to @obchardon

Comment: Or simply B = `A.*cumsum(A==23,2)`

Comment: @obchardon that's even better, why I even thought about using `find` I have no idea.

Comment: it's friday ;) Oh and by the way: perhaps that it's more secure to use : `B = A.*(cumsum(A==23,2)>0)` (so if there is more than one 23 per line it will still work)

Answer (score 1):

find() returns the row and the column of the desired value, in your case "23", in matrix A.
using a for loop you can copy the value and its following ones:

```
A = [23 34 45 0 0 0; ...
    21 34 0 0 23 11; ...
    34 23 0 0 0 22];
[r, c] = find(A==23);

B = zeros(3,6);

for i=1:length(r)
    columns = c(i):length(B);
    B(i,columns) = A(r(i),columns);
end;
```